# complete non-compact Riemannian manifolds and critical points

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For a complete non-compact Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature positive, it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by known result. Choose a point $p$ on the manifold, is it possible that the distance function $d(p, \cdot)$ has a sequence of critical points going to the infinity of the manifold?

Comment: Sectional curvature is positive or nonpositive?

Comment: strictly positive sectional curvature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a classical result.

Let $q_1,\dots,q_n$ be a sequence of critical points  such that $$|q_{n+1}-p|\ge 2\cdot |q_n-p|.$$
By Toponogov's comparison, 
$$\measuredangle [p\,^{q_i}_{q_j}]\ge \tfrac\pi3.$$
Hence we get a bound on $n$.

Comment: What about $3$-dim complete Riemannian manifold with $Rc> 0$? Schoen-Yau had proved it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it also true that all critical points with respect to a fixed point $p$ is in a compact set?@Anton Petrunin